# sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA from cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run file. I ran this command in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
```

When I ran the above command, I got the following error message.

```
sh: 0: Can't open cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
```

Comment: you can try opening a terminal and changing directories to where the file is located .. then try `sudo ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run` maybe that will work

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the guideline in nvidia website mentions .run while it is -run in the file you download. trying following would solve the problem:

```
sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains the cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run file and run this command:

```
sudo sh ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem for another version of Ubuntu, I passed that by removing `-run` or `.run` from the end of command as follows:

```
sudo sh cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux
```